# Simple question: Euclidean versus Hermitian form

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

This may be a basic question, but why is the inner product of bra and ket Euclidean inner product [[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation#Inner_products_and_bras)] and not more general Hermitian form? [[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Examples)] Is there something fundamental stating that $M$ should equal the identity?

Answer (score 1):

I would rather answer your question in a different way. I request you to be patient as the start diverges a bit from your question. There is a recent upsurge due to finding real eigenvalues for Non-Hermitian matrices and this has led to the idea of generalising hermiticity of operators in QM to something else, known as Pseudo-Hermiticity.

If you study them you will know that idenity as a metric is important for Hermitian matrices or else they do not form a Complete orthogonal vector space i.e. a Hilbert space. In fact Gram Schmidt orthogonalization will also not work in such a case !

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: What do you mean *"iden[t]ity as a metric is important for Hermitian matrices or else they do not form a Complete orthogonal vector space"*? Gram-Schmidt diagonalization works for arbitrary inner products, it's just that "arbitrary inner products" doesn't actually mean anything because they can all be isometrically mapped to the standard inner product.

Comment: When did I say Gram Schmidt orthogonalization does not work for arbitrary inner products, I meant if you use Hermitian matrices and a non-identity matrix as a metric, then 
"G-S-O" will not work until the metric is not changed to what it should be i.e. identity. I am new to the physics stackexchange, but giving a score of -1 before clarification, is'nt it like being a bit ignorant? No hard feelings though.

Answer (score 0):

1. The inner product on a finite-dimensional "bra-ket space" is *not* "Euclidean", as that denotes the standard inner product on Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is, however, in the case of $\mathbb{C}^n$ given by
   $$ x^\dagger y = \sum (x^i)^\ast y^i,$$
   the Wikipedia article is just wrong about calling this Euclidean.
2. Every complex inner product space $(V,\langle\dot{},\dot{}\rangle)$ of dimension $n$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$ with this standard inner product, so allowing arbitrary Hermitian forms is not a generalization. The isomorphism is just given by choosing an orthonormal basis of $V$ and mapping this to the standard basis in $\mathbb{C}^n$.